# Why am I forced to spatially filter Dynamic World data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I was working with [Dynamic world](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/GOOGLE_DYNAMICWORLD_V1#description) data following the tutorial series. The following code works and display actual data:

```js
var START = ee.Date('2021-04-02');
var END = START.advance(1, 'day');

var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(ee.Geometry.Point(20.6729, 52.4305)),
    ee.Filter.date(START, END));

var dwCol = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1').filter(colFilter).first();
```

but the following results in all filtered pixel:

```js
var START = ee.Date('2021-04-02');
var END = START.advance(1, 'day');

var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.date(START, END));

var dwCol = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1').filter(colFilter).first();
```

Why is it compulsory to filter by date and geometry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last snippet works fine, it's probably just rendering the image where you're not looking.

```
var START = ee.Date('2021-04-02');
var END = START.advance(1, 'day');

var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.date(START, END));

var dwCol = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1').filter(colFilter).first();
Map.centerObject(dwCol)
Map.addLayer(dwCol)
```

Note that `dwCol` is a bit confusing variable name. It's actually an image, not a collection after you called `first()`.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f76c5cd2143ba84e90db44fe93d575d7

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you are very right I should call mosaic() instead. Sorry for the variable convention I simply kept the one from the exemple.